# Return Axios promise to several callers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, axios

I'm currently building a microservice using Express. To retrieve an access token for a second microservice, I send a HTTP POST request to a token endpoint via axios. To reduce traffic and to simplify token management, a new token should only be requested when the current token is expired. If a new token is requested because the previous one expired, all callers should wait for this token instead of requesting several new tokens. To achieve this, I implemented the following class `Auth` that is instantiated as singleton:

```
class Auth {
   getToken() {
        if (this.token && !isExpired(this.token)) {
            return Promise.resolve(this.token);
        }
        if (!this.tokenPromise) {
            this.tokenPromise = axios
                .post(...)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log("received token");
                    this.tokenPromise = null;
                    this.token = response.data.token;
                    return response.data.token;
                })
                .catch(() => null);
        }
        return this.tokenPromise;
    }
}

// export Auth class as singleton
module.exports = new Auth();
```

However, when I call `getToken` the returned promise never resolves and the statement `console.log("received token");` is never called. For testing purposes I changed my code and returned another Promise instead of the axios promise:

```
class Auth {
   getToken() {
        if (this.token && !isExpired(this.token)) {
            return Promise.resolve(this.token);
        }
        if (!this.tokenPromise) {
            this.tokenPromise = axios
                .post(...)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log("received token");
                    this.tokenPromise = null;
                    this.token = response.data.token;
                    return response.data.token;
                })
                .catch(() => null);
            this.secondPromise = Promise.resolve("fakeToken");
        }
        return this.secondPromise;
    }
}

// export Auth class as singleton
module.exports = new Auth();
```

In this case both the returned promise and the axios promise resolve when calling `getToken` and `console.log("received token");` is called. What is the reason for that and how could I achieve the desired behavior?

**Minimum working example**

During creation of this minimum working example, it turned out that the problem only occurs when calling the `getToken()`method from an axios interceptor (I followed these [examples](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/754) when creating the async interceptor). You can reproduce the issue with this minimum working example:

mwe.js:

```
const axios = require("axios");

class Auth {
  getToken() {
    if (!this.tokenPromise) {
      console.log("get token");
      this.tokenPromise = axios
        .post("https://example.com")
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("received token");
          this.tokenPromise = null;
          return response;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("err", err);
          this.tokenPromise = null;
          return null;
        });
    }
    return this.tokenPromise;
  }
}

const auth = new Auth();

axios.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    const token = await auth.getToken();
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log("interceptor error", error);
  }
);

axios.get("https://example.com");
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "mwe",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "minimum working example",
  "main": "mwe.js",
  "scripts": {},
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2"
  }
}
```

When running `node mwe.js` the message `"get token"` is logged, but not `"received token"`.

Comment: I don't see why `return this.tokenPromise` wouldn't ever resolve unless your axios call never resolves.  Other than that, it looks correct.  I suspect there's something else going on that isn't showing in this code.  On another issue, it does seem like you're missing `this.token = response.data.token` to actually cache the token you got for future requests.

Comment: As my code works if I use another promise instead of the axios promise and the axios promise resolves when not returning it, I'm wondering if the described issue is a bug of axios. Your second point is right, I added this line in the example code.

Comment: Like jfriend said, this should work fine. The only questionable bit is `.catch(() => null);` - in an error case, you usually do not want to return nothing as if it was a normal result value, and you still want to unset `this.tokenPromise`. Also add a log statement in there, maybe the promise rejection is the reason for not logging "received token"?

Comment: I already have checked this, I omitted this line in my example code for the reason of simplicity.

Comment: When using [request](https://github.com/request/request) instead of axios everything works fine, but I'd like to use axios as I'm already using it for my other requests.

Comment: Can you show us an actual minimal, reproducible example that we can run and see the error ourselves.  There's nothing theoretically wrong with the code you show and axios should work just fine.  So, there is apparently something else going on here (perhaps some axios defaults set weirdly or it isn't imported correctly or something that isn't apparent from the code you show).

Comment: I just added a minimum working example. The issue only occurs when calling ```getToken()``` from an axios interceptor. Possibly I use the async axios interceptor in a wrong way?